# How to check if user clicked "ignore" when asked for an application to be authorized?

Tags: facebook, titanium

This is the facebook login event handler :

```
function facebookLoginHandler(e) {

        Ti.API.error("--)))+++   e.success   : "+e.success);

        if (e.success) {

            Ti.API.error("fb login success");
            Ti.API.info('user id ' + facebook.uid);


            //SELECT uid,first_name,last_name,sex,pic_square,email,birthday_date,current_address,current_address.street,current_address.city,current_address.country,current_address.zip,email,last_name,locale,sex,pic,pic_big,pic_small,profile_url FROM user WHERE uid=me()

            facebook.request('fql.query', {query: "SELECT first_name,last_name,sex,email,birthday_date,profile_url FROM user WHERE uid="+facebook.uid
                },  function(r) {

                    Ti.API.error("facebook.request CallBack fn is RUNNING");
                    Ti.API.info('r.success ' + r.success);


                    Ti.API.error("--)))+++   r.success   : "+r.success);

            if (!r.success) {
                if (r.error) {
                    alert(r.error);
                } else {
                    alert("call was unsuccessful");
                }
                return;
            } else {
                var result = JSON.parse(r.result);

            Ti.API.info('r.result ' + r.result);

            Ti.API.info('result[0].email : ' + result[0].email);
            Ti.API.info('result[0].profile_url : ' + result[0].profile_url);
            Ti.API.info('result[0].sex : ' + result[0].sex);
            Ti.API.info('result[0].birthday_date : ' + result[0].birthday_date);
            Ti.API.info('result[0].last_name : ' + result[0].last_name);
            Ti.API.info('result[0].first_name : ' + result[0].first_name);

            if (Titanium.Network.networkType === Titanium.Network.NETWORK_NONE) {

               alert(L('indisp_cnnx_msg'));
            } else {
                //////  
                //  le controller suivant est  global scopped pour pouvoir l'annuler une fois on a plus besoin!!
                // c'est pas CON
                /////   
                Alloy.Globals.getJsonArrayByHttpCtrl = Alloy.createController('getJsonArrayByHttp');
                Alloy.Globals.getJsonArrayByHttpCtrl.getJsonArrayByHttp("userHasAccreq", "ws-bookmynight.php?op=verifyUser&email="+result[0].email+"&fb="+result[0].profile_url);
            }
            }




            // for (var c=0;c<result.length;c++)
            // {
                // var row = result[c];
                // Ti.API.info('c  : ' + c);
                // Ti.API.info('row[0].first_name  : ' + row.first_name);
            // Ti.API.info('row[0].last_name : ' + row.last_name);
            // Ti.API.info('row[0].birthday_date : ' + row.birthday_date);
            // Ti.API.info('row[0].profile_url : ' + row.profile_url);
            // Ti.API.info('row[0].email : ' + row.email);
            // Ti.API.info('row[0].sex : ' + row.sex);
            // }

            // for (var c=0;c<result[0].length;c++)
            // {
                // Ti.API.info('result['+c+'] ' + result[c]);
                 // //var row = result[c];
            // }

        });

        } else if (e.error) {
            // Error!
        } else if (e.cancelled) {
            // cancelled by user
        }
    }
```

The "e.success" is always set to true wether "ignore" or "Ok" are clicked.
How to control this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After first Facebook authorization and app tries to reauthorize user will see message: "You have already authorized

If you want to test what will happen when user doesn't authorize your app you have to go to your **[Facebook test account settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications)** and remove your app from that list to remove all permissions. Then when you click "Cancel" you will get "User cancelled the login process." error event:

```
{
      bubbles = 1;
      cancelBubble = 0;
      cancelled = 1;
      code = "-1";
      error = "User cancelled the login process.";
      source = "[object facebook]";
      success = 0;
      type = login;
}
```

Comment: If the app is removed from the facebook account as you said and then the user will get an authorization request this will be as for a first authorization request. What i need is not related to the first authorization request ignored by the user(removing the app from the account won't happen each time the user logouts..) but for the following requests. Is an error message for a first time request is all what i can get ?

Comment: Now i think that the reauthorization message is useless (it's not for an instant authorization that the user is requested for..). So wether the user re-validate or ignore it's the same if already he has authorized the app once.

Comment: Yes, your second comment is correct. In best case scenario your app should be designed in such way that user will never see reauthorization message.